# iOS Metal Performance Shaders Image Upsample

Tags: ios, gpu, metal

For iOS App with the Metal Performance Shader, I would like to write a GPU accelerated function for CNN average pooling layer back propagation. This pretty much is the same as image upsample. For example, if the input is

```
2 5 6
3 6 7
8 9 0
```

the Upsampled image should be

```
2 2 5 5 6 6
2 2 5 5 6 6
3 3 6 6 7 7
3 3 6 6 7 7
8 8 9 9 0 0
8 8 9 9 0 0
```

I have written the following kernel funciton:

```
kernel void upsample(texture2d<float, access::read> inTexture [[texture(0)]],
                     texture2d<float, access::write> outTexture [[texture(1)]],
                     uint2 gid [[thread_position_in_grid]])
{
    const float4 color = inTexture.read(gid);

    uint2 p;
    p = uint2(gid.x * 2, gid.y * 2);
    outtexture.write(color, p);
    p = uint2(gid.x * 2 + 1, gid.y * 2); 
    outtexture.write(color, p);
    p = uint2(gid.x * 2, gid.y * 2 + 1);
    outtexture.write(color, p);
    p = uint2(gid.x * 2 + 1, gid.y * 2 + 1);  
    outtexture.write(color, p);
}
```

But I am not sure if this is correct. How do I know the original "gid" is related to the coordinates in the input texture but not the output texture?

Comment: As a side note, if you're looking to maximize performance with large datasets, my experience suggests that you'd achieve significantly improved performance by using fixed GPU hardware to do this. Just set up a render pipeline, load a texture, configure your properly sized render target, set your texture sampler to 'nearest' magnification, and let the fixed hardware do the scaling. In other, similar tests I've conducted I saw fixed hardware doing this kind of thing several times faster than a compute kernel.

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote looks correct to me, assuming you dispatched a grid that has the same dimensions as the source texture.

There is no inherent correspondence between the thread position in the grid and the coordinates you read or write. `gid` is simply a point in the grid of work items you dispatched with your compute command encoder. In your kernel, you can interpret this however you want. If you dispatch a 2D grid and you're working on textures, it often makes sense to treat `gid` as a pair of coordinates, as you're doing here.

You could also have dispatched a 1D grid and "wrapped" it to a 2D grid yourself, but using a 2D thread position can save you an (expensive) integer division in the kernel, in addition to being more intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

@fireman
I profile your up sampling code, but it cost expensive for writing 4 data one by one.
And your question about gid. it is related to work items of you kernel process area for input and output texture. Maybe it contain 1 pixel in input and contains 4 pixels for output.

Answer (score -1):

This need is now handled by the MPSCNNUpsampling family of kernels. See MetalPerformanceShaders/MPSCNNUpsampling.h

Comment: I know this was in August, but this does not necessarily do the job as if the OP wants to only use a MTLTexture, it might be a costly operation to do the conversion just for an upsample.